# Loop through an array and push it into array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So i try to loop an Array and push it into object within this code:

```
   const past7Days = [...Array(7).keys()].map(index => {
var date = new Date();

  const local = new Date();
  local.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
  local.setDate(date.getDate() - index);

  return local.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
});
let data={};
let arr=[]
for (var i = 0; i < past7Days.length; i++) {
    console.log(past7Days[i]);
  return arr.push(data["key"] = past7Days[i]) 
}
```

what i expected is :

```
[{key:"date"},{key:"date2"}]
```

can somebody tellme where did i do wrong here

Comment: In an object, you can't have duplicate keys.
Try inputting `{key:"date",key:"date2"}` to the console, you'll see something like `{key: 'date2'}` as the evaluation result. When you assign to `data["key"]`, you overwrite any older value.

Comment: any recomment to ovveride it?

Comment: is that possible to make it {key:"date"},{key:"date2"}

Comment: Why would you want an object with just one key and that key always being `key`? Can you explain how that is useful? Why not an array of dates?

Comment: because i am going to use the key:"dates" on my bootstrap vue table as field @trincot thats why i try to make it always being key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt there is only **one** such object created  (`data`) and the assignments to `data[key]` just keep overwriting the same object's property. Moreover, that `push` will not push an object, but the string that is assigned.

You can create each object immediately in your first iteration, with a `{ key: string-value }` object literal and returning that.

Unrelated, but you should not use `getTimezoneOffset` like that. In boundary cases (like when daylight saving switches on the same day) it can have undesired results. Instead consider that you can convert a date to a string with respect of the current locale's timezone. For instance, the Swedisch locale also uses "YYYY-MM-DD" format (like `toJSON`), and when used with `toLocaleDateString` it will use the locale's date:

```js
const past7Days = Array.from({length: 7}, (_, index) => {
    const local = new Date();
    local.setDate(local.getDate() - index);
    return { key: local.toLocaleDateString('en-SE') };
});
console.log(past7Days);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want exactly one array where the elements are like {"key": `<string representation of a date>` }, you can try this:

```js
const past7Days = [...Array(7).keys()].map(index => {
var date = new Date();

  const local = new Date();
  local.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset());
  local.setDate(date.getDate() - index);

  return local.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
}); 
let arr=[]
for (var i = 0; i < past7Days.length; i++) {
    // console.log(past7Days[i]);
    arr.push( {key: past7Days[i] } ) 
}
console.log(arr);
```